# How can i reset my Gmail password from inbuilt Google settings of android if 2FA is enabled?

Tags: gmail, google-account, 2fa

I've recently changed my gmail password and now i forgot password before this time i was able to reset it by OTP that Google sent to my number for verification but this time i enabled 2FA and Google asking some more steps to verify like when is my account was created.

I submitted all the things together with an email address to reach me but at the last it shows 'Google couldn't verify it's you'.

Please, Is there any solution and steps where i can change this in my Google App for android ?

*My account don't have any recovery email, it includes only phone number for verification.*